# Uniform buffer size on Nvidia GPUs

Tags: c#, opengl, nvidia

I use C# with OpenTK to access OpenGL API. My project uses tessellation to render a heightmap. My tessellation control shader splits a square into a grid of 64 squares and my tessellation evaluation shader adds vertical offsets to those points. Vertical offsets are stored in a uniform float buffer like this:

```
uniform float HeightmapBuffer[65 * 65];
```

Everything works fine, when I run the project on my laptop with AMD Radeon 8250 GPU. The problems start when I try to run it on Nvidia graphic cards. I tried an older GT 430 and a brand new GTX 1060, but results are same:

```
Tessellation evaluation info
----------------------------
0(13) : error C5041: cannot locate suitable resource to bind variable "HeightmapBuffer". Possibly large array.
```

As I researched this problem, I found `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE` variable which returns ~500MB on the AMD and 65.54 kB on both Nvidia chips. It's a little strange, since my array actually uses only 16.9 kB, so I am not even sure if the "BLOCK SIZE" actually limits the size of one variable. Maybe it limits the size of all uniforms passed to one shader? Even so, I can't believe that my program would use 65 kB.

Note that I also tried to go the 'common' way by using a texture, but I think there were problems with interpolation, so when placing two adjacent heightmaps together, the borders didn't match. With a uniform buffer array on the other side, things work perfectly.

So what is the actual meaning of `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE`? Why is this value on Nvidia GPUs so low? Is there any other way to pass a large array to my shader?

Comment: `float` uniforms are actually the size of a `vec4` so you have `4 bytes * 4 * 65 * 65` = `67.6 KiB`.

Comment: Hrm, I'm having a hard time sourcing that info in the GL spec so take it with a grain of salt.  I *might* be remembering the ES 2.0 spec.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in Geometry Shader from large array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262469/error-in-geometry-shader-from-large-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I researched this problem, I found `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE` variable which returns ~500MB on the AMD and 65.54 kB on both Nvidia chips.

`GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE` is the wrong limit. That applies only to [Uniform Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object).

You just declare an array

> ```
> uniform float HeightmapBuffer[65 * 65];
> ```

outside of a uniform block. Since you seem to use this in a tesselation evaluation shader, the relevant limit is `MAX_TESS_EVALUATION_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` (there is a separate such limit for each programmable stage). This *component* limit counts just the number of float components, so a `vec4` will consume 4 components, a `float` just one.

In your particular case, the latest GL spec, [GL 4.6 core profile] (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)
at the time of this writing, just guarantees a minimum value of 1024 for that (=4kiB), and you are *way* beyond that limit.

It is actually a very bad idea to use plain uniforms for such amounts of data. You should consider using [UBOs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), [Texture Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture), [Shader Storage Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) or even plain textures to store your array. UBOs would probably be the most natural choice in your scenario.

Comment: @PeterMcG: the question clearly states that this is about the tesselation evaluation shader, not the control one. The default uniform block isn't a uniform block in the sense of `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE`, which only applies to UBOs. The naming might be unfortunate, but the spec is very clear on that.